# How can I get all logs about android devices in my App?

Tags: android, logging

I use the below code to get device log

```
 Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat");
```

but I find that the log just about my own App.
Is there any possible to get all logs in android devices?

Answer (score 0):

Due to security and privacy reasons you only get the logs of your own app.
You'd need a rooted device to access logs of other apps too.

Comment: if the device is rooted,how can I do?

Comment: I think the exec("logcat") returns all logs then, but I'm not sure. Just google it.